# Using a trivial Omit radically changes how Partial works on generic functions arguments. Why?

Tags: typescript

I have an union type in the core of my project.

```
type Shape = {kind: "circle", radius: number} | {kind: "square", size: number};
```

And I've decided to have a function to handle all the internals of updating a Shape

```
function update<T extends Shape>(obj: T, values: Partial<T>) {}
```

Because of my thorough typing, typescript does not allow me to do this:

```
const aShape = {} as Shape
aShape.size = 4 // this fails, because aShape could be a Circle
```

However with my update function it allows me to do all kind of weird things:

```
const aShape = {} as Shape
// this pass types checking even when Shape does not _always_ supports `size`
update(aShape, { size: 3 });
```

I kinda grasp the concept of excess property, and I kinda get why `{ size: 3 }` satisfies `Partial<Shape>`. However I don't get why `{ unrelated: 3 }` won't.

But the **weirdest** thing I found, and I can't wrap my head around it, is that if I define my function using a non-op Omit modifier it behaves completely different:

```
type Shape = {kind: "circle", radius: number} | {kind: "square", size: number};

function update<T extends Shape>(obj: T, values: Omit<Partial<T>, "dont_care">) {}

const aShape = {} as Shape;
// this fails, as if you were trying to assign `size` to a `Shape`
update(aShape, { size: 3 });
```

This is the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=29&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0lAvFA3gawJYDsAmAXFAEQDG2ATmQDYQkA0UlC%202ArgM7G7sC2AIwiUAvlAA%20GHAWIlOAR3YJK9Jp2wAvCD35DRAbgBQhgPQmAZu1xlg2APa4o7MPgTAIAHgAqUCAA93Ak5YREgAPgAKOwEAK2IvJgA3BBp2CG4oAAVlWxTvMIBKDBFjS2tbBycXN08ff0D8YPgkCEjouKgEqGTU9OIAeT5sYA9sylyafKYSfAdgAH0yZXpC4uMyB05gKARm5DR0MQQm0IgjQ2dXdwjd06Z0KHUtYgBmKBEC-SA):

I am not sure what kind of answer I am expecting. Maybe if someone could explain why omitting a non-existing prop would radically change how typescript check my function calls it will make me more comfortable to production release such thing. Thanks for reading, cheers!

Comment: The issue is that `Omit` does not distribute across unions, so `Omit<A | B, "xxx">` is *not* the same as `Omit<A, "xxx"> | Omit<B, "xxx">`.  If you want that behavior you could create a `DistributiveOmit`.  See the linked questions/answers for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But In terms of `keys`, at least in my particular case `Omit<A|B, "irrelevant">` seems to be equivalent to `Omit<A, "irrelevant"> | Omit<B, "irrelevant">` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwglgJwMYBtoF4oG8DWcB2AJgFxQBESiqEZANFAgIaFwCuAzqfqwLYBGEBPXYB7HhGAALAgHNS7YAlkBfANwAodaEhQAygEdWjBBmx4ipMu0PGawuAC8IXXgIRRhYidPxyoCpV81TW1oXUlGHUx4ZDQoAB89GxMNLXBoAHkeOGAAQShMLJyAHhjqejJEEzQAN0Z8YDIAPgSoIuBigyMTCqqIWvrGppD0tuzgACECsZKyuMSu216Eaog6hubUpBF8BShGaaxlffYZvI1t3eAoPkPjxlP2idTQqABpCBB2DIAzfMwcJ8RD8zrkNK8Pl9flMAUCQU9VEA

Comment: Just because two types have the same keys doesn't mean they're the same type; and `keyof (A | B)` is equivalent to `keyof A & keyof B`, so `keyof` and unions often surprise people.  Notice that [those two types are not equivalent](https://tsplay.dev/WokJpW).

Comment: Actually my problem is with Partial that behaves differently when it's applied to an argument in opposition with an in scope declared var [see example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwglgJwMYBtoF4oG8DWcB2AJgFxQBESiqEZANFAgIaFwCuAzqfqwLYBGEBPXYB7HhGAALAgHNS7YAlkBfANwAodaEhQAygEdWjBBmx4ipMu0PGawuAC8IXXgIRRhYidPxyoCpV81TW1oXUlGHUx4ZDQoAB89GxMNdQAzVnwkYDgRfChWMEJGYAgACgA3RhRSAAVjHOqAHnDIiAA+AEpsdSg+qCQ8hShGKEwqlAA6JhYODWVNQuLSsqwZtk4oACZlTvUgA).

Comment: I probably need to rephrase my question, because Omit is not the source of my issues, actually it was a weird way of fixing them. Thanks for all your answers